# Usage of Defense vs. Defence in tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

One thing I realized when adding a tag to an article is that the various 'defenses' could also be spelled 'defences', depending on the locale.

Eventually what I see happening is multiple tags appearing for the same defense, such as 'sicilian-defense' and 'sicilian-defence'.

Is there a convention that is preferred for the tags? should one be set?

Wikipedia does not set a convention other than the usage should be consistent within an article.

Comment: Coming up with a convention and setting up tag synonyms to cover the other spelling sounds like a great plan. :)

Comment: Ah, yes it looks like the tag synonyms will handle this case nicely

Comment: IIRC `defense` is more common in American English, so I think that should be the standard.  No SE site I know of synonymizes alternate spellings, that would be a mess (there are a lot more words that just this one to consider).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My opinion based on looking at my collection of chess books would be to use the Americanized "Defense".

Setting up tag synonyms might help if we have enough questions, but right now the only tags I found are as follows:

- [sicilian](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sicilian)
- [damiano-defence](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/damiano-defence)
- [philidor-defence](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philidor-defence)
- [scandinavian-defence](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scandinavian-defence)
- [alekhines-defence](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alekhines-defence)
- [grunfeld-defense](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grunfeld-defense)

I would recommend changing the tags in place since there is only the one question for the each of them (except for Sicilian) and the titles also need to be standardized.

Comment: I have just gone through and changed all instances of "defence" to "defense" (also changing [tag:sicilian] to [tag:sicilian-defense]).

Comment: 'french-defense' and 'french' should also be made synonymous.

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen good call, I just merged [tag:French] into [tag:French-Defense].

Comment: You should also merge the tag 'defence' with 'defense'.

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen thanks, good catch, that's done now.